# can i do a limited beta of a spotify app?

Tags: spotify

Was wondering, once I submit a concept and it is approved, whether I am able to test my app with real Spotify users before submitting it for general availability. If so, how would I do that? I'd expect I could have a page that people can accept the conditions and click to accept, then it would install the app in their installation but it would not be visible in the general app store. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no managed test environment available. If you want to test the app, you have to distribute the app bundle manually and ask the Spotify user to get app developer permissions on developer.spotify.com